# Taking input from an array of integers in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, input

All, I'm pretty new to C++. My teacher gave us the assignment of creating a function that would do the following:

```
//addbig( ) -- This function is sent an array of integers and the length 
//of the array.  
//It returns the sum of all integers in the array that are larger than 1000.
```

Maybe because, English is my second language, but I don't really understand what he is asking here.

Also, when taking input from the user, I was using cin >> when the arrays would be made of characters. But I tried to use it to receive input from an array of integers and is not letting me do that. Do I have to do a conversion first?

If any of you could shed some light, it would be great.

Comment: Doesn't sound like you are taking input from the user. You just need to make a function that takes in two parameters: an array of integers, and the size of the array who returns the sum of all integers in the array larger than 1000.

Comment: If you are responsible for reading the integers from a file (or the keyboard) before passing them to the assigned function then just `file >> x;` where x is an int and not a char.  The stream is properly overloaded

Answer (score 1):

I think you should start with the functions parameters.  It says addBig has two parameters an array of integers and the length of the array.

```
int addBig(int arr[], int sze)
{
     int sum = 0;
     // do summation.
     return sum;
}
```

Comment: Note that the first parameter is not an array but actually a pointer. :)

Comment: Yeah I generally prefer to use pointers for this sort of thing.  The only time I would actually use this (instead of say a vector) is if I wanted the function to work with different data structures.  Who still uses arrays?  I edited anyways for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

As for the input of integers

```
const size_t N = 10;
int a[N];

std::cout << "Enter " << N << " integer values: ";
for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) std::cin >> a[i];
```

As for the function then you should declare it as

```
int addbig( int a[], size_t n );
```